# My custom "paste from clipboard" action

Tags: java, c++, linux, windows, clipboard

I want to find a way to do kind of a custom "paste from clipboard" action. Let's assume the content of clipboard is text for simplicity (not a file). Whenever you press `Ctrl+V`, it inserts that content (which is text) to a current open file which has a focus.

I have an app for catching a **global** hotkey. Note this is not a window application, it's a console one and it catches the hotkey **globally**. Let's say I have the hotkey of `Ctrl+U`. So what I want to do is when I press `Ctrl+U` I want to insert some predefined text to a current open file. Just like `Ctrl+V` does! The differences from a standard `Ctrl+V` is that I want to insert a **predefined** text and the hotkey is **different**.

How do I do this?

I'd prefer a cross-platform solution, however first of all I'm going to do that for Linux, specifically Ubuntu. The language is not important but Java or Scala would be better. Of course, I understand that the solutions is Java uses native OS' API for that.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have a few clarification questions. Is the current open file open in your java application, or in some random text editor? Also, do you already have the code for the event for the hotkey, or should that also be part of the answer?

Comment: @Bucco, in any text editor. I have the code for the hotkey as I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping that this hackish solution would work, but it is still untested, I am unsure how to catch the event for the hotkey.

The idea behind this code is the following five steps:

1. Get the old text in the clipboard and temporarily save it
2. Paste our predefined text into the clipboard
3. Trigger the global paste event
4. Release the global paste event
5. Reset the clipboard to the old text

This should give the appearance of a new clipboard (if not, hopefully it inspires you to come up with a better, less hackish solution).

Without further ado, here is my code. First I have a simple helper method to set the value of the clipboard (as we do this twice).

```
public static void setClipboard(String s) {
    StringSelection contents = new StringSelection(s);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(contents, contents);
}
```

And then, I have a main method where I go through the five steps in order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Step 1 ) get old text
    String oldText = "";
    try {
        oldText = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor); 
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
        ufe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Step 2 ) paste our text in clipboard
    setClipboard("This lorem ipsum predefined string blows my mind.");

    // Step 3 ) trigger paste event
    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException awte) {
        awte.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);

    // Step 4 ) Release paste event
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);

    // Step 5 ) Reset clipboard
    setClipboard(oldText);

}
```

[Edit]:

Here is some code to test what kind of contents are in the Clipboard - image, text, etc. The unicode error was coming from the fact that the old contents of the clipboard were something that couldn't be represented by a plain String. To fix this error, you will have to check if the old contents were an image, the old contents were text, and save them accordingly.

```
public static int kindOfContents() {
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);

    if(contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
        // String, save temporarily as string and write back as string
        return 0;
    } else if(contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.imageFlavor)) {
        // Image, save temporarily as BufferedImage and write back as image
        return 1;
    } else if(contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
        // List of files, save temporarily as java.util.List interface and write back as the file lists
        return 2;
    }

}
```

If the contents are text, then for saving and writing the content you would use the old method, repasted below for convenience.

```
// Step 1 ) get old text
String oldText = "";
try {
    oldText = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor); 
} catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
    ufe.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}

// Step 5 ) Reset clipboard
setClipboard(oldText);
```

However, if the contents are an image, then for saving temporarily and rewriting you need to do the following. Note that the code for writing the image is not mine, but is taken from the accepted answer at  [Setting images to Clipboard - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834768/setting-images-to-clipboard-java)

```
// Step 1 ) get old image
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = (BufferedImage) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
} catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
    ufe.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Taken from [Setting images to Clipboard - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834768/setting-images-to-clipboard-java) :

```
// Step 5 ) Reset clipboard
ImageTransferable transferable = new ImageTransferable( image );
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(transferable, null);

static class ImageTransferable implements Transferable
{
    private Image image;

    public ImageTransferable (Image image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
        throws UnsupportedFlavorException
    {
        if (isDataFlavorSupported(flavor))
        {
            return image;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
        }
    }

    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported (DataFlavor flavor)
    {
        return flavor == DataFlavor.imageFlavor;
    }

    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors ()
    {
        return new DataFlavor[] { DataFlavor.imageFlavor };
    }
}
```

Comment: that's an interesting solution.

Comment: for some reason I get `java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException: Unicode String` even though I'm working an English text. Why?

Comment: @Alex this is when it is trying to save the old contents, that are not standard text. If you don't care about the old contents you can comment out steps 1, and 5. Otherwise, you will need to see if it is a string, or an image. I'll add more code to do that now.

Comment: Are you sure that even the contents in the clipboard before were English text? (and not just the stuff you will be putting in)

Comment: yes, it's working now, it was my miss I guess. However, it works oddly: sometimes it inserts a new text, sometimes does not. I can't figure out why is that.

Comment: Hmm that's a little weird, but I guess it is expected because the solution is a little weird/hacky. Maybe try including a Thread.sleep(50); in between steps 3 and 4 to give some time to the computer for it to realize that an event has been triggered? You would need to find a happy medium for that time though, if it is too long it would paste several times.

Comment: sometimes it returns "()" for "kindOfContents" which is Unit and throws an exception "java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException: Unicode String"