# Initiate cut / copy / paste action programmatically

Tags: java, swing, action

I would like to add `Cut` / `Copy` / `Paste` items into my context menu I already have available in my `JTree` control.

I would like those actions just to initiate the default actions "cut", "copy", "paste" actions already implemented by the default `JTree`, with as little boilerplate code as possible. I have checked the actions are available in the ActionMap on the tree, I can do getActionMap().get("cut") to get the corresponding action, but I do not know how to proceed - there is a method called `SwingUtilities.notifyAction` (this is used when processing the default key bindings in the tree), but this method requires a few parameter values I do not have ready.

I expect the code could like a bit like this, only a different method needs to be used instead of `notifyAction`, or perhaps some sensible values could be contstructed for missing parameters:

```
        Action action = tree.getActionMap().get("cut");
        if (action != null) {
            SwingUtilities.notifyAction(action);
        }
```

Comment: See this answer by Vineet Kosaraju: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343716/my-custom-paste-from-clipboard-action

Comment: @ManojVadehra Thanks for effort, but this definitely seems too verbose for the purpose. I have no intention of implementing clipboard operations, they are already implemented in the container, I just want to trigger or call the existing implementation.

Comment: `new JMenuItem(action)` <- Basically use the `Action` with a `JMenuItem`.  You might find you need to supply the text for the button though, but see where it takes you

Answer (score 0):

"I would like to add Cut / Copy / Paste items into my context menu I already have available in my JTree control."

Are you talking about a JPopupMenu? If yes, you can add JMenuItem for cut, copy and paste then just use addActionListener() on all of them.