# How to get and set data of clipboard?

Tags: java, clipboard

I am trying to store the content of my clipboard in a variable. So I can use it later and set it again to the clipboard content. I found a lot of other questions about the topic. But they all asked for the clipboard content as a string. I want the pure data.

I tried following approach:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ClipboardTest {

    static Object data;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        Clipboard board = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        Transferable t = board.getContents(null);
        DataFlavor[] df = t.getTransferDataFlavors();

        for (DataFlavor f : df) {
            if (f.isFlavorJavaFileListType()) {
                try {
                    data = t.getTransferData(f);
                } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (data != null)
            board.setContents((Transferable) data, null);
        else
            System.out.println("Data is null :(");
    }
}
```

The idea came from dragging files into a JFrame. Where I used pretty similar code. But it was just guessing and it´s defenitily not working. My data is `null` and nothing seems to work.

I really couldn´t find anything on the internet. So I hope you can help me.

Comment: You're calling `f.isFlavorJavaFileListType()` which is only true if the data in clipboard is a list of files. It's not the raw data of the file, it's its path on the filesystem. If you copy a file in your explorer and then run your code, you should see that `data` gets assigned (but then the cast to `Transferable` fails). What is your `pure data` that you're trying to store?

Comment: That makes sense. But as I sad I am just guessing here because I couldn´t find anything online and I just worked once with Transferables and all this stuff. 
I am trying to store everything a clipboard can store. Strings, files, maybe images? I don´t know how all of this is implemented. I thought about the clipboard as a datastream which I can just store in an object.

Comment: By default I believe there's only an implementation of a String (StringSelection), indeed. For other objects you'll need to implement your own Transferables. See e.g. images here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834768/setting-images-to-clipboard-java

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I just figured something out. It is acually way simpler than I thought. I am going to post it as my own answer. But wow. I hate it if I can solve the answers myself. It´s always so embarrassing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach can be way simpler for the clipboard data

```
Clipboard board = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
Transferable data = board.getContents(null);    // get clipboard content
board.setContents(data, null);                  // set clipboard content
```